# Pegar o próximo evento com Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho um sistema do qual pega o agendamento do dia corrente e o próximo agendamento, vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para pegar o agendamento do dia corrente, fiz dessa forma:

```
// DataAgenda = NOW()
mysqli_query($this-conexao,"SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE DATE(DataAgenda) = CURDATE()");
```

E o próximo evento, como posso pegá-lo?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
mysqli_query($this-conexao,"SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE DATE(DataAgenda) > CURDATE() ORDER BY DataAgenda LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Se o registro do próximo evento estiver antes do atual vai dar ruim :D... Aliás, se houver um registro antes que seja numa data posterior que não o próximo, vai retornar ele.

Comment: Não se esqueça de adicionar um `order by DataAgenda`. O que voce faz é pegar o primeiro registro com a `DATE(DataAgenda) > CURDATE()`. Isso não garente que seja o próximo evento.

Comment: Bem observado William. Obrigado.

Comment: Desculpe dvd, não consegui entender.